# GTA IV Windows 7 Compatibility Mode

Tags: windows-7, compatibility

Windows 7 is NOT listed in compatibility mode for GTA IV
Or any other problem in particular.
How do I fix it to show windows 7?

Comment: Which OS are you currently running?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 7 already as your Operating system, then it wouldn't show it in the list of 'run this program in compatibility mode'.
That is because, the `Compatibility mode` feature was introduced so that the older programs written for the older version of the windows, would be allowed to run on Windows 7.

To go deeper-
32 bit Windows has emulation for 16 bit programs built in. 64-bit Windows only has emulation for 32 bit programs. If the program ran on 32-bit Windows 7 and not 64 bit, then chances are it's a 16 bit program and you may have to use something like `DosBox` or `XP Mode` to be able to run it in 64-bit Windows.

And similarly, windows 8 would have Windows 7 along with windows xp and vista in the compatibility mode.